# Dependency Injection for access to current User

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, dependency-injection, rx-swift

I'm trying to level up as a developer, and am currently building an app using RxSwift with MVVM. Most of my view models need access to the `current user` object. In just about every view controller, before I do anything, I have to fetch info for `current user` from database, and only then, can all other code be executed ( because so much of the logic depends on the state of the `User`). This also means most code is at least nested one level since fetching user is async. I actually input `User` into initializer of view model. There must be a better way to persist the current user throughout app. Ive recall reading a bit about dependency injection and how it allows data to be passed along as dependencies to other objects. Is this a scenario where injection could be a viable solution? Im open to other suggestions as well!

**Potential solutions I've thought of since time of post**

- just pass along `User` through segues and assign to currentUser property in each view controller
- after login, create a shared observable of type `Observable<User>` in RootViewController, and subscribe to it wherever need be. But i'd still have to put code into subscription block wherever i subscribe.

Comment: Putting the user into the initialiser of the view model *is* dependency injection.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. I guess what my main concern is- and what I think is a code smell is the fact that I have to fetch the same current User in each view controller, thus violating DRY. Right?

Comment: It doesn't necessarily violate DRY.  DRY would apply if you had to perform the same operation several times in a class and wrote the code each time instead of writing a function to perform that operation.   You could also move that function into the model class or wherever.  Just to clarify; you shouldn't fetch the user from the network each time; you should pass it to the view model initialiser; if you need to pass it via `prepareForSegaue` first to do that, then do that.

Comment: Gotcha. I have a singleton class named `AuthService` which handles signing in amongst other things. Since signing in is the first order of business when app launches, I will fetch `User` at this time, and assign it to a property `currentUser` within `AuthService`, for use throughout the app. Unless I hear any objections to this.

Comment: i always make accManager singleton which handles user login/logout etc, work as suppose to